# How to implement a conditional filter in R dplyr filter

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, conditional-statements

I have the following data with two columns and 15 rows:

```
data_1 <- structure(list(column_1 = c(120, 130, NA, NA, NA, 130, 182, 130, 
NA, 925, NA, 181, 182, 188, NA), column_2 = c(7, NA, 1, 1, 1, 
3, 7, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

|  | column_1 | column_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 120 | 7 |
| 2 | 130 | NA |
| 3 | NA | 1 |
| 4 | NA | 1 |
| 5 | NA | 1 |
| 6 | 130 | 3 |
| 7 | 182 | 7 |
| 8 | 130 | NA |
| 9 | NA | 1 |
| 10 | 925 | NA |
| 11 | NA | 1 |
| 12 | 181 | NA |
| 13 | 182 | 1 |
| 14 | 188 | 1 |
| 15 | NA | 1 |

- By using filters, I would like to keep the oberservations with the following values in column_1: `NA`, 130, 181, 182, 188
- Furthermore, I would like to remove all observations with the entry 7 in column_2

So far, this works by the following code:

```
data_1 %>% filter(is.na(column_1) | column_1 %in% c(130, 181, 182, 188), !column_2 %in% 7)
```

Now I want to add an additional filter: If the value is 130 in column_1 and in column_2 it is a `NA`, then remove the oberservation (so the rows 2 and 8 in data_1). How could I do this? What are the best ways to achieve this conditional filter? I have tried the following commands so far, which do not lead to the desired result:

```
data_1 %>% filter(is.na(column_1) | column_1 %in% c(130, 181, 182, 188), !column_2 %in% 7) %>% filter(case_when(column_1 == 130 ~ !is.na(column_2)))
```

The result here is that only the entry 130, 3 is kept.

```
data_1 %>% filter(is.na(column_1) | column_1 %in% c(130, 181, 182, 188), !column_2 %in% 7) %>% filter(case_when(column_1 == 130 ~ !is.na(column_2), TRUE ~ is.na(column_2)))
```

Now two entries remain: 130, 3 and 181, `NA`

I have also tried the following two commands:

```
data_1 %>% filter(is.na(column_1) | column_1 %in% c(130, 181, 182, 188), !column_2 %in% 7) %>% filter(if (column_2 == 130) !is.na(column_2))
data_1 %>% filter(is.na(column_1) | column_1 %in% c(130, 181, 182, 188), !column_2 %in% 7) %>% {if (column_2 == 130) filter(., !is.na(column_2))}
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for something like this?

```r
library(tidyverse)


data_1 |>
  filter(case_when(
    is.na(column_1) ~ T,
    column_1 == 130 & is.na(column_2 ) ~ F,
    column_2 == 7 ~ F,
    column_1 %in% c(130, 181, 182, 188) ~ T,
    T ~ F
  ))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    column_1 column_2
#>       <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1       NA        1
#>  2       NA        1
#>  3       NA        1
#>  4      130        3
#>  5       NA        1
#>  6       NA        1
#>  7      181       NA
#>  8      182        1
#>  9      188        1
#> 10       NA        1
```

I just added all of your conditions to one big `case_when`. Make sure to map the statements to `T` and `F` so that the filter works correctly. In this case, when the condition is mapped to `T` you will keep the row and when it is `F` you will remove the row.

Comment: It’s strongly discouraged to use the `T` and `F` shortcuts instead of `TRUE` and `FALSE`, since `T` and `F` are variables that are freely redefinable (and, being single-letter names they’re also not as readable).

Comment: Thanks, @KonradRudolph for the advice. I had not thought of that before; however, your advice makes sense to me. I always appreciate feedback towards making my code better.

Comment: Thank you very much @ AndS. ! Unfortunately, with this code, not only observations with NA in column_1 are kept (which is want I want), but also when they have a 7 in column_2 (entries in column_2 with 7 are always to be removed, independently of the entry in column_1). Why does this happen? And does anyone see what was wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I would only add that structure(list()) may be needlessly high level here unless it is done for another reason. Simpler would be:

```
data.frame(column_1 = c(120, 130, NA, NA, NA, 130, 182, 130, NA, 925, NA, 181, 182, 188, NA), 
           column_2 = c(7, NA, 1, 1, 1, 3, 7, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1)))

# or

tibble::tibble(column_1 = c(120, 130, NA, NA, NA, 130, 182, 130, NA, 925, NA, 181, 182, 188, NA), 
               column_2 = c(7, NA, 1, 1, 1, 3, 7, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1))
```

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks! So far I have always used the dput() function (which delivered the code like I have posted it) because I didn't know another way to get the code without typing it by hand. With which command did you do that?

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you want an HTML-like output there are a number of ways. In package sjPlot there is tab_df. Assign your df/tibble then print using sjPlot::tab_df(data). There are also various datatable options in various datatable packages. (Note: Output comes to rstudio Viewer, not Console.